# Java API for UCP (Universal Computer Protocol)

Tags: java, sms

Does anyone know of a good Java library that can send/receive SMS-messages using UCP?

Comment: http://www.java4less.com/RSmsUcp_help.html

Comment: did you find appropriate lib? This one only send smsjava4less.com/RSmsUcp_help.html

Answer (score 0):

http://smslib.org/ is good too.

Comment: UCP is not specifically mentioned in that library. Are you sure that is what is uses?

Comment: So does it use UCP? Can it receive not only send sms?

Comment: Doesn't support UCP. Older v3 version did support SMPP, but even then that is discontinued in newer v4 version.